# How to pass data from a web page to an app which is about to be installed on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, web

Is this possible to achieve on iOS and Android with the least manual operation?

1. The user visit the web page W and W stores data D somewhere (in the device or the server).
2. The user install app A and A get D (from the device or the server).

I can only think two ways to indirectly achieve the same result:

- W asks the user to copy D into the device's clipboard, and then A asks the user to paste D in the app.
- W asks the user to write some random string X (and save the mapping from X to D), and then B asks the user to type X (and get D by sending X to backend).

Btw, after googling a while, it looks like current mobile browsers cannot access the clipboard, and W3C is just writing the draft of clipboard API (2014/09/18 http://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/ ), so using clipboard as a "hack" to pass data automatically is not possible currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We also struggled with this when we built our last mobile app, Kindred Photobooks. We actually created a native library for iOS and Android to do just this - give you the ability to pass data past install. The best way we found is to basically bundle that information in the link and use fingerprinting to make that data available after install, which is working really well.

You can try to build fingerprinting in in house as well - basically create an outstanding device fingerprint once someone clicks on the link and match it to the fingerprint that you create once a user

We automated everything and made sure all the edge cases work on both Android and iOS. Check us out at [branch.io](http://branch.io) and if you are curious on how our links work, [you can read more here](https://medium.com/@madalina/how-to-make-app-content-as-accessible-as-web-content-f6b19e970bf).

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly what you want to do, but, you can for example, on the web page, ask the user to enter some info, and then you send to his email a code, then he can share that code with other people, and inside the application, you create a section, so user can enter a code. Using that code, the app makes an HTTP call to the server, and the response can be the info entered by the first user. Of course you are going to need a database.